# indented block after 'while' statement, dont know what to change to make it worth

Tags: python

```
while True:

        print("please enter username")

input()

username = input()

if username == "Elias":

break

        print("username correct")

break;



while True:

        print("please enter password")

input()

password = input()

if password == "1234567890":

break

        print("access granted");



print("rechner:")


variable_a = input("alle noten mit + zeichen eintippen")

print("Dein Durchschnitt ist", input()/2);
```

---

```
 File "C:\Users\Odyesp\PycharmProjects\pythonlearning.py\main.py", line 3
    print("please enter username")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'while' statement on line 1
```

Comment: You have a *lot* of indentation issues in this code. It's not clear that the code shown here produces the error shown, as the error implies you didn't indent that call to `print` *at all* relative to the preceding line.

Comment: Your indentation is absolutely crazy and almost impossible to read. Delete the extra blank line right after your while declaration, and it should work. Just to let you know, the command to stop a program screaming at you to enter a password nonstop is `Ctrl`+`C` ;)

Comment: @code : 'it should work' is a little optimistic; it will simply yield ANOTHER error...

Comment: @Swifty yes, but that error will no longer be present, even if replaced by a thousand more.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you may be very new to Python, and that's perfectly ok! We were all really new at some point.

For your use case, I think it's important to step back and analyze what you're wanting to do.

1. Capture a username
2. Continue trying to capture a username until it is "Elias"
3. Capture a password
4. Continue trying to capture a password until it is "1234567890"
5. At the end, print "access granted" and "rechner:"

Here's some code:

```
# Capture username, and only proceed if "Elias"
username = ""
while username != "Elias":
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
print("username correct")

# Capture password, and only proceed if "1234567890"
password = ""
while password != "1234567890":
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
print("access granted")

print("rechner:")
```

Here's an example of the output from the terminal, along with my inputs
[image]